# HTML5 transparent div height overlaps container height with video or iframe tag

Tags: css, html, video

I have a container that contains 2 divs a transparent background color that sits on top of the video tag, the video should be full screen width 100% (height does not matter)

For some reason the transparent div is overlapping the video container height slightly (on the bottom) as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v3vLq0nv/

This does not happen for an image tag, note for this example I have used an embedded youtube iframe as it has the same problem as the  tag.

If I set a height on the parent container then it works fine, but setting a fixed height for the parent container makes the video not full width anymore.

The only thing I found that does work is actually change the HTML5 declaration from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

Which I guess means it's HTML5 anymore which is not a great solution.

Note doing this in jsfiddle will not make it work as jsfiddle itself will put the declaration back in the frame "!DOCTYPE html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best two options here are:

```
#videoContainer { height:150px; }
```

or

```
#videoContainer iframe { float:left; }
```

They will both solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome I can't believe float:left worked, so simple! I can't set the height of the container or the video won't be full width anymore thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to iframe :)

Comment: Awesome this also worked, I didn't video and iframe tags are not block!